# A question on integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

It's often assumed that regulated function are integrable. Meaning that:
$U\left( {f,P} \right) = L\left( {f,P} \right)$ for a partition $P$ of the interval $[a,b]$ and that

$$U\left( {f,P} \right) = L\left( {f,P} \right) = \int\limits_a^b {f\left( x \right)dx} $$

My idea is that we can use that fact that it is a regulated so we can use step functions for that. However, I dont know how to proceed. Any ideas? If you have some kind of official proof/ reference, it would be helpful too.

Comment: What is your definition of a regulated function?

Comment: For an $\varepsilon  > 0$, there exists some step function $\varphi$ such that ${\left\| {f - \varphi } \right\|_\infty } < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Here $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$, correct?

Comment: @Math1000 yes it's correct.